# Read a specific string from an xml file c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Hi i need to extract a specific string form my xml file. How can i go about this? i have searched the internet but cant find an answer specific enough for me to understand. ^^

I want to get my SavePath string using the corresponding GameName

heres my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Game>
  <entry>
    <GameName>test</GameName>
    <SavePath>C:\Users\allen\Downloads\GameOfLife\GameOfLife\obj\Debug\CoreCompileInputs.cache</SavePath>
    <ExePath>C:\Users\allen\Downloads\GameOfLife\GameOfLife\obj\Debug\GameOfLife.exe</ExePath>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <GameName>test2</GameName>
    <SavePath>C:\Users\allen\Downloads\GameOfLife\GameOfLife\obj\Debug\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs</SavePath>
    <ExePath>C:\Users\allen\Downloads\AdobeAIRInstaller.exe</ExePath>
  </entry>
</Game>
```

and here's the code I've been trying to use

```
var xmlStr = File.ReadAllText(Properties.Resources.docname);
var str = XElement.Parse(xmlStr);
var result = str.Elements("entry")
    .Where(x => x.Element("GameName").Value.Equals(SelectGame_Combobox.Text))
    .Descendants("SavePath")
    .ToString();
```

Comment: What happens when you run your existing code?

Comment: Why can't you serialize it to an object ?

Comment: Also does the above code compile ? because Where returns an IEnumerable collection which don't have a Descendents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there.  Just get rid of `ToString()` so it returns a collection of `XElement` (just one, of course), and then you can get it like this:

```
var result = str.Elements("entry").
    Where(x => x.Element("GameName").Value.Equals(search)).Descendants("SavePath");

string value = result.First().Value;
```